# How to pull and display records between A-G, H-P and Q-Z

Tags: php, mysql

I want to query a table in a mysql database and display the results in a list format like this:

A - G, H-p, Q-z

So all results with the first letter of their name starting with A to G will display under A - G and so on.

What is the best way to do this in php? can it all be done in the query itself? Or will I have to sort it in the php.

Got any examples of something similar?

Comment: Do you want to categorize them on a single page or is it your intention to have some sort of pagination and show only one group of entries at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name < 'H';
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name >= 'H' AND name < 'P';
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name >= 'P';
```

Or, in one query,

```
SELECT *, 
    CASE 
        WHEN name < 'H' THEN 'A-G' 
        WHEN name >= 'H' AND name < 'P' THEN 'H-P' 
        ELSE 'Q-Z' 
    END AS category
FROM table ORDER BY name;
```

Comment: name will be the string with length more than one

Comment: This seems to work fine. having trouble with the logic of displaying the results in a table form though.

Comment: What kind of trouble? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ASCII(name) BETWEEN 65 AND 74 -- ASCII Code for A and G
```

Works only with regular characters, not with characters like ö,ä,ü,é,ê,è...

Answer (score 0):

There are two strategies:

- **you display all records in sections A-G,H-P,Q-Z**

  Select all records with `ORDER BY name` and during display process check when you cross next section.
- **you display records from A-G,H-P or Q-Z on demand (for example after click)**

  After user selection event you fetch records with SQL `WHERE SUBSTRING(name, 1, 1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'G'` for A-G range